# Getting both semi-axis of an ellipsoid by knowing its surface area.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I know that the spheroid has a surface area, $A$, of $900cm^2$ and that its semi axis $a$ and $c$ are such that $c = 0.707a$. I wish to know the values of $a$ and $c$.

There's this formula which approximates the surface area of an ellipsoid (I'm not sure if its correct, I couldn't find it anywhere besides Wikipedia):

$$A = 4\pi(\frac{a^pb^p+a^pc^p+b^pc^p}{3})^{1/p}, p \approx 1.6075$$

In this case, since its an ellipsoid of revolution, $a = b$ and the expression can be simplified to:

$$A = 4\pi(\frac{a^pa^p+a^pc^p+a^pc^p}{3})^{1/p} = 4\pi(\frac{a^{2p}+2a^pc^p}{3})^{1/p}=4\pi(\frac{a^{2p}+2a^p(0.707a)^p}{3})^{1/p} \equiv$$
$$\equiv 3(\frac{A}{4\pi})^p=a^{2p}+2a^p(0.707)^p$$

It would be solved by "passing" everthing, except for the $a$ to the left ($a$ as a function of $A$) and injecting the values. Sadly, I do not know how to proceed from that last step, if it is even possible. But, if there's any other way of getting there, please point it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a substitution with $h = a^p$ and you'll end up with a quadratic equation.